# Finding the total price for each album

Tags: database, sqlite

[Chinook Database SQL Lite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jABbr.png)

I am trying to run a query from the well-known Chinook Database above that will give me the total price for each album. I have attempted to use the LEFT JOIN operator to retrieve data from the two tables that have the data I need to answer this question. The result I get is the sum of the unit prices but only the name of one album title. The goal is to get the title of EACH album and their total prices.

*This is SQLite so the FULL Outer Join would not work in this case*

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
SELECT (a.title), SUM(t.UnitPrice) AS TotalPrice
FROM albums a
LEFT JOIN tracks t
ON t.albumid = a.albumid
ORDER BY a.title;
```

Any response would be appreciated!

Comment: ORDER BY a.title && a.price;

Comment: Take some time to read about SQLite syntax for aggregation: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/

Comment: @titleLogin thank you for the comment! I used GROUP BY T.UnitPrice, a.title and I was able to get the desired output